# Excel file validation in laravel dose not work

Tags: excel, laravel, validation

```
$this->validate($request,
[
   'file'=> 'required|mimes:xlsx'
]);
```

When i try to upload a .xlsx file, the validator fail.

Comment: Try to debbug file mime type by $file->getMimeType()

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42091682/6329802

Comment: can you print your all request and check the file uploaded correctly and what extension does it contain by like this dd($request->all());

Comment: Be sure, the file is not empty, I lost 4 hours trying with an empty file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try below code like:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
  [
      'file'      => $request->file,
      'extension' => strtolower($request->file->getClientOriginalExtension()),
  ],
  [
      'file'          => 'required',
      'extension'      => 'required|in:xlsx,xls',
  ]

);
```

And you also check from your controller like:

```
if(Input::hasFile('import_file')){
    $uploadedFileMimeType = Input::file('import_file')->getMimeType();

    $mimes = array('application/excel','application/vnd.ms-excel','application/vnd.msexcel');

    if(in_array($_FILES['import_file']['type'], $mimes)){

        //True
    } else{

        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withFlashDanger("Please select Only Excel File");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that it will not work if you forgot to put

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

in your html form tag to work with files!