# Laravel Validator only works for fails

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to validate the upload file in laravel.

The file only accepts `xlsx,xls and csv`

I have this working code from my controller

```
  public function project_import_excel(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'file' => 'required|max:5000|mimes:xlsx,xls,csv'
    ]);

    $modal = "active";

    if($validator->passes()){
        return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->with(['success'=>'File uploaded successfully!'])
        ->with('modal',$modal);
    }else{
        return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->with(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()])
        ->with('modal',$modal);
    }
}
```

and I have this sessions for `errors and success` in my `blade` file

```
 @if(session('errors'))
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">  
        @foreach($errors as $error)
           <li>{{$error}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <hr>

 @elseif(session('success'))

    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> 
       {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
    <hr>

 @endif
```

If I try to upload `.jpeg` or any other file that is not `xlsx, xls, or csv`

This will give me a message like

[image]

But if I upload  a file like`

[image]

The success message doesn't want to show up. Is there anything wrong with my `if else`?

The problem is, it always end up to `session('errors')`

**UPDATE** 
I tried to remove this `mimes:xlsx,xls,csv` and the `session('success')` works fine. But how can I validate which files are acceptable or not?

My `HTML` code for `form`

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="bulkProjMod" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <!--Header-->
     <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Upload Projects List</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
     </div>
     <!--Body-->
     <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="container">

        @include('main.projectlistRedirectBack')

        <p class="note note-success">
            <strong>Note upload:</strong> 
            You are trying to upload multiple project records that containas multiple task records. This record will be useful to any transaction
            <br>
            *format : <b><em>xlsx,xls,csv</em></b><br>
            </p>

            <form action="{{ url('/projectlist/project_import_excel') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="file-field">
                <div class="btn-sm float-left">
                    <span>Choose file</span>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>


    </div>
    <!--Footer-->
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submitImport" class="btn btn-success waves-effect" id="upBulkSubmit">Upload</button>
        </form>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

tried this one `dd($validator);`

[image]

Comment: Try with status: `redirect()->back()->with('status', 'File uploaded successfully!')->with('modal',$modal);` . Then in blade `@if (session('status')) <div class="alert alert-success"> {{ session('status') }} </div> @endif`

Comment: I also tried to change the variable `success` to `status` but still getting the same

Comment: did you have  enctype="multipart/form-data" on your form?

Comment: Yes, I have this attribute on my form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: can you dd the `request` or `$validator` to see if file is there when you upload excel file?

Comment: pls check the updated question to see the `dd();`

Comment: what is inside array data? (data: array: 3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link given by @porloscerros

[Laravel validator and excel files error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089659/laravel-validator-and-excel-files-error/42091682#42091682)

This answer, solved my problem!

```
   $validator = Validator::make(
    [
        'file'      => $request->file,
        'extension' => strtolower($request->file->getClientOriginalExtension()),
    ],
    [
        'file'          => 'required|max:5000',
        'extension'      => 'required|in:,csv,xlsx,xls',
    ]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the followings:

```
@elseif(Session::has('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  {{ Session::get('success')}}
</div>
@endif
```

or

```
 @else(session('success'))

    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> 
       {{ $success }}
    </div>
    <hr>

 @endif
```

Comment: Tried your options but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
return redirect()->back()
    ->withErrors($validator)
    ->with([
        'modal' => $modal
    ]);
} else {
return redirect()->back()
    ->with([
        'success'=>'File uploaded successfully!'
        'modal' => $modal
    ]);
}
```

and

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">  
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
       <li>{{$error}}</li>
    @endforeach
</div>
<hr>
@else
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> 
   {{ session('success') }}
</div>
<hr>
@endif
```

Hope it will works

Comment: Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to show success and errors message to separate condition:

```
if($validator->passes()){
    return redirect()
    ->back()
    ->with('success', 'File uploaded successfully!')
    ->with('modal',$modal);
}else{
    return redirect()
    ->back()
    ->with(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()])
    ->with('modal',$modal);
}
```

And then view file:

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
     <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> 
         {{ Session::get('success') }}
     </div>
@endif


@if(session('errors'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">  
       @foreach($errors as $error)
           <li>{{$error}}</li>
       @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```